# Are Emily and Corvo members of the Abbey of the Everyman?

Tags: religion, dishonored

In *Dishonored* and *Dishonored 2*, the Abbey of the Everyman’s Overseers are a really powerful anti-Outsider, almost militant, group that is shown to like to murder people for such small things as having Bonecharms and Runes. The Abbey is the state religion. However, Emily gets the Mark in the second game, and her father, Corvo, got it in the first game.

**Do the empress and Royal Protector believe in the religion, or is it just the state religion because it’s too powerful to get rid of?**

Comment: Note that it is possible for them to believe it (though that is unlikely considering their interactions with the Outsider) and still not want it to be the state religion.  Which would make both parts true...  Or if Empress Jessamine - or any other predecessor - didn't believe in it, but couldn't get rid of it, that would make the second part true irrespective of the first part.